# Inconsistencies in the review summaries of suggested edits

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

In short, since this a bit tricky:

- The question, before the editor's edit, didn't have the [software-installation](/questions/tagged/software-installation) tag;
- The question, after the editor's edit, still didn't have the [software-installation](/questions/tagged/software-installation) tag;
- The question, after the reviewer's approval and edit, had the [software-installation](/questions/tagged/software-installation) tag;
- In the review, under the "differential" (pre editor's edit and post editor's edit) version of the question's body, instead of the "differential" (pre editor's edit and post editor's edit) version of the tags, the "final" (post reviewer's edit) version of tags is shown.

---

Currently, in the review summary of a suggested edit on a question (at least when the suggested edit was approved and edited), you're shown (correctly) **the "differential" (pre editor's edit and post editor's edit) version of the body** and (under the former, incorrectly) **the "final" (post reviewer's edit) version of the tags**:

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Link to the [suggested edit's review](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/479749) and link to the [question's revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/405484/revisions).

**Update**: A similar thing also affects review summaries of suggested edits where the suggested edit was rejected and the post edited; you're shown (correctly) **the "differential" (pre editor's edit and post editor's edit) version of the title and of the tags** and (incorrectly) **the "final" (post reviewer's edit) version of the body**:

[image: screenshot3]

[image: screenshot4]

Link to the [suggested edit's review](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/484848) and link to the [question's revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/691762/revisions).